# Exchange or o365

Tags: email, exchange, email-server, microsoft-office-365

this may be a stupid question, so I apologize in advance.

But how can I find out if an email is an o365 account or an exchange server. So for example office@heizoele-sternath.at.

With nslookup and set type=mx I get this below, but I can't find out what kind of account it is.

```
heizoele-sternath.at
Server: 10.221.255.1
Address: 10.221.255.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
heizoele-sternath.at mail exchanger = 10 mail.heizoele-sternath.at.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
heizoele-sternath.at nameserver = ns2.world4you.at.
heizoele-sternath.at nameserver = ns1.world4you.at.
mail.heizoele-sternath.at internet address = 81.19.149.36
ns2.world4you.at internet address = 176.97.158.6
ns1.world4you.at internet address = 192.174.68.6
ns2.world4you.at has AAAA address 2001:67c:10b8::6
ns1.world4you.at has AAAA address 2001:67c:1bc::6
```

Can you please help me here?

Thank you and LG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can’t, reliably. The MX record just tells MTAs where to send email directed to a certain domain and by itself contains no information on what server software the recipient is running.
You can draw some conclusions about the mail filtering used by the recipient by looking at the MX record - `somedomain.mail.protection.outlook.com` sounds a lot like a Microsoft controlled domain, for example - but that’s pretty much it. They may well be running Postfix servers behind an M365-based mail security solution.

Perhaps a more important question is what problem you are trying to solve by trying to identify the kind of mail service the recipient is utilizing.

Comment: The point is that we at Forensic would like to know where the email accounts are to be backed up from before any house searches.

Comment: I understand. No, you’ll need to do other kinds of research. For legal requests I’m sure all large service providers will act in accordance with local laws, but DNS records only help you identify whether or not a company uses an external party as an ingress for email; nothing about the details of what happens afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

With the given information nobody can say for sure which technologies are used. All obvious indicators does not point to MS.